# EOF error generated in a unit test, but not if I run it myself

Tags: python-3.x, eof

I get an EOF error even though my code runs fine

I have tried simplifying my code and searching for syntax errors, but it runs fine.

```
sentence = input('Enter a sentence or phrase: \n')

print('You entered: ', end='')
print(sentence)

def get_num_of_characters(inputStr):
    print()

    return len(inputStr)

def output_without_whitespace(strpo):

    caki = strpo.replace(' ','')
    return caki


print('Number of characters:',get_num_of_characters(sentence))
print('String with no whitespace:',output_without_whitespace(sentence))
```

The output of number of characters and character string without whitespace work fine until a unit test is run, then I get an EOF error.

Comment: your unit test probably expects an _argument_ not standard input. can you show how you're testing your code?

Comment: No, the user just inputs a sentence like "I like cake." and the code is supposed to output what the user imputed, number of characters of input, and the input returned without whitespaces.

Comment: understand that noone can reproduce your error unless you provide a [mcve]